# Should an Error with a source include that source in the Display output?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have an error type that impls the `Error` trait, and it wraps an underlying error cause, so the `source` method returns `Some(source)`. I want to know whether the `Display` impl on my error type should include a description of that source error, or not.

I can see two options:

1. Yes, include `source` in `Display` output, e.g. "Error opening database: No such file"

This makes it easy to print a whole error chain just by formatting with `"{}"` but impossible to only display the error itself without the underlying chain of source errors. Also it makes the `source` method a bit pointless and gives client code no choice on how to format separation between each error in the chain. Nevertheless this choice seems common enough in example code I have found.

2. No, just print the error itself e.g. "Error opening database" and leave it to client code to traverse and display `source` if it wants to include that in the output.

This gives client code the choice of whether to display just the surface error or the whole chain, and in the latter case how to format separation between each error in the chain. It leaves client code with the burden of iterating through the chain, and I haven't yet fallen upon a canonical utility for conveniently formatting an error chain from errors that each only `Display` themselves excluding `source`. (So of course I have my own.)

The snafu crate (which I really like) seems to hint at favoring option 2, in that an error variant with a `source` field but no `display` attribute defaults to formatting `Display` output that does not include `source`.

Maybe my real question here is: What is the purpose of the `source` method? Is it to make formatting error chains more flexible? Or should `Display` really output everything that should be user-visible about an error, and `source` is just there for developer-visible purposes?

I would love to see some definitive guidance on this, ideally in the documentation of the `Error` trait.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum DatabaseError {
    Opening { source: io::Error },
}

impl Error for DatabaseError {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        match self {
            DataBaseError::Opening { source } => Some(source),
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for DatabaseError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            DatabaseError::Opening { source } => {
                // ??? Should we include the source?
                write!(f, "Error opening database: {}", source)

                // ??? Or should we leave it to the caller to call .source()
                //     if they want to include that in the error description?
                write!(f, "Error opening database")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, error messages should contain as much information as possible. If I run my program, see "Error opening the database" as an error message I then need to open the file where the line is which returned this error value, add debug code, run it again and get it to return the same error again. But if I knew from the beginning that it couldn't find the DB file I could skip all of that and be done with it faster

Comment: @MindSwipe Agreed, but this question is not about how much information to show the user. It is about how to build the plumbing that shows it to them.

Comment: [RFC201](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0201-error-chaining.md) describes the thinking when the Error trait was introduced, with reference to [Java's chained exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr** - Either include the underlying error in the source chain, or append the source message on `Display`, but *not both*. Your mileage may vary though.

The two options of whether to print the source error on a `Display` implementation creates two schools of design. This answer will explain the two while objectively stating their key differences and clarifying a few possible misconceptions in the way.

#### Design 1: Yes, include `source` on your `Display` impl

Example with SNAFU:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    #[snafu(display("Could not read data set token: {}", source))]
    ReadToken {
        #[snafu(backtrace)]
        source: ReadDataSetError,
    },
}
```

The key advantage, as already mentioned in the question, is that providing the full amount of information is as simple as just printing the error value.

```rust
eprintln!("[ERROR] {}", err);
```

It is simple and easy, requiring no helper functions for reporting the error, albeit with the lack of presentation flexibility. Without string manipulation, a chain of colon-separated errors is what you will always get.

```
[ERROR] Could not read data set token: Could not read item value: Undefined value length of element tagged (5533,5533) at position 3548
```

#### Design 2: No, leave out `source` on your `Display` impl

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    #[snafu(display("Could not read data set token"))]
    ReadToken {
        #[snafu(backtrace)]
        source: ReadDataSetError,
    },
}
```

While this will not give you the full information with a single line print like before, you can leave that task to a project-wide error reporter. This also grants the consumer of the API greater flexibility on error presentation.

A simple example follows. Additional logic would be required for presenting the error's backtrace.

```rust
fn report<E: 'static>(err: E)
where
    E: std::error::Error,
    E: Send + Sync,
{
    eprintln!("[ERROR] {}", err);
    if let Some(cause) = err.source() {
        eprintln!();
        eprintln!("Caused by:");
        for (i, e) in std::iter::successors(Some(cause), |e| e.source()).enumerate() {
            eprintln!("   {}: {}", i, e);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f560c0a1b3ef924b110ed83909fdc85d)

It's also worth considering the interest of integrating with opinionated libraries. That is, certain crates in the ecosystem may have already made an assumption about which option to choose. In [`anyhow`](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow), error reports will already traverse the error's source chain by default. When using `anyhow` for error reporting, you should *not* be adding `source`, otherwise you may come up with an irritating list of repeated messages:

```
[ERROR] Could not read data set token: Could not read item value: Undefined value length of element tagged (5533,5533) at position 3548

Caused by:
   0: Could not read item value: Undefined value length of element tagged (5533,5533) at position 3548
   1: Undefined value length of element tagged (5533,5533) at position 3548
```

Likewise, the [`eyre`](https://crates.io/crates/eyre) library provides a customizable error reporting abstraction, but existing error reporters in the `eyre` crate ecosystem also assume that the source is not printed by the error's `Display` implementation.

#### So, which one?

Thanks to the efforts of the Error Handling project group, a key guideline regarding the implementation of `Display` was proposed in early 2021:

> An error type with a source error should either return that error via `source` or include that source's error message in its own `Display` output, but never both.

That would be the **second design**: avoid appending the source's error message in your `Display` implementation. SNAFU users can use its Report API (available since [version 0.7.2](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#072---2022-10-09)), or bring in a custom error reporter. As the ecosystem is yet to mature around this guideline, one may still find error utility crates lacking support for error reporting in this manner.

#### In either case...

This decision only plays a role in error reporting, not in error matching or error handling in some other manner. The existence of the `source` method establishes a chain-like *structure* on all error types, which can be exploited in pattern matching and subsequent flow control of the program.
The `Error::source` method has a purpose in the ecosystem, regardless of how errors are reported.

In addition, it's ultimately up to the developers to choose how to design their errors and respective `Display` implementations, although once it starts integrating with other components, following the guideline will be the right way towards consistent error reporting.

#### What about Rust API guidelines?

The Rust API guidelines do not present an opinion about `Display` in errors, other than [C-GOOD-ERR](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#c-good-err), which only states that the error type's `Display` message should be *"lowercase without trailing punctuation, and typically concise"*. There is a [pending proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/api-guidelines/pull/210) to update this guideline, instructing developers to exclude `source` in their `Display` impl. However, the pull request was created before the guideline was proposed, and has not been updated since then (at the time of writing).

See also:

- The error handling protect group ([GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-error-handling))
- [Inside Rust Blog post 2021-07-01: What the error handling project group is working towards](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2021/07/01/What-the-error-handling-project-group-is-working-towards.html)

Comment: Thank you - this is a spectacularly thorough answer, with very helpful links. It prompts me to wonder if it might be helpful for the formatter to understand something like "{:s}" to format using the Error trait, traversing sources and separating them with colons. That could reduce friction for wider adoption of option 2.

Comment: I can't edit the post, but since rust 1.51 the loop using `std::iter::successors` doesn't compile like this and needs a slight adjustement, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81460

Comment: @iliis The code in the answer still works, since the error is passed by value, rather than by reference.